# How could someone with Magic wield the Anti-magic weapons?

Tags: black-clover

The Witch Queen told Asta and his friends a bit about the history of the elves in Black Clover Episode 65. She stated that the elves possessed great magical abilities and were so strong that many of them were her equal in terms of magical strength (and she is very prideful; for her to admit that says a lot.)

What is really baffling me thou is when she stated that the leader of the elves was the former wielder of the Anti-Magic weapons that Asta currently uses, which subsequently blew Asta's mind and mine too!

[image]

**How is it possible if people with Magic can't wield them?** 
We know that the only reason that Asta can use those swords is because he was born without magic and hence the sword does not weaken him. However, the leader of the elves possessed strong magical powers and yet he could still wield the Anti magic weapons. Even the Wizard King admitted that only people without Magic could wield those weapons. Are there any exceptional rules to how the Anti magic weapons work?

Comment: She says they're the remnants of the weapons wielded by the Elf leader, and in the flashback they looked very different to Asta's ones (much shinier). It's possible that they weren't anti-magic back then, or they worked differently.

Comment: Yea but then they could have gotten old and dulled in appearance @ConMan I guess thats a possibility thou

Comment: Maybe through a curse seal technique.

Comment: I feel like this is the kind of question where the answer is potentially "Wait until they explain it in the show/manga itself".

Comment: I'll have to agree with ConMan, this is something we have to wait for the official explanation, we would just be speculating. For the longest time, I assumed some sort of Kamijou Touma thing was going on with Asta.

Comment: @pboss3010   in a sense Anti magic is actually very similar to imagine breaker tbh, they can both nullify all forms of magic and supernatural effects/entities, Asta is just better off in many ways.

Comment: I was referring more to that it was hinted (and in later in the series outright said) that the imagine breaker is holding something back in Touma, where we haven't gotten that kind of hint with Asta.

Comment: @ConMan remember when Yami and licht fought, I rewatched it and here is what litch said: "Why do you have that grimoire? How did you get the demon dwelling sword and the demon slayyer sword? Those swords belong to the master!" This indicates that the sword has not changed at all because he called it by the original names so I'm sure at this point that the elf elder wielded them while they had anti magic

Comment: ALso @ConMan remember when Asta used his sword to unknowingly absorb Noels Magic? the sword started glowing, this could signify that there's some unknown mechanism towards using the swords to absorb magic rather than cancel or redirect. And during the flashback, both swords were glowing, meaning they were charged with mana, which is funny cause the swords are anti magic and are supposed to cancel magic, but then I guess there's a way they can be used to absorb magic or redirect, depending on some wierd factors

Comment: Honestly, I don't remember any of that, because I'm not the main person in my household watching the show. But yes the fact that his sword has some kind of special history has been there from the start. What that history actually is, will presumably have to wait another 100 chapters.

Answer (score 2):

From recent manga all of this has been answered.

Three swords already have the ability we see today with the exception of anti magic. That is the Demon slayer sword already had the ability to cut and deflect magic when Licht was the owner of this grimoire. (This is why Licht was able to cut the storm in which Tetia the princess was stuck.) Similarly the Demon dweller sword already had the power to absorb surrounding people and the owner magic spells and release it as flying slash and to glow after it has absorbed certain amount of magic and the Demon destroyer sword other than able to cut magic and spells. It also already had the ability to absorb and remove the effect of spells.

So anyone with magic would have been able to wield them. This is why they were present in a four leaf grimoire because of its tremendous strength and also before this grimoire became five leaf grimoire these swords were shiny. It is after the grimoire became a five leaf grimoire and housed a demon that they became dark and shady and were able to absorb anti magic from the grimoire in which the demon resides.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they could use magic that levitates swords but the "levitation/gravity magic" doesn't "physically contact" the swords, or at least it drains the mana slower.

Answer (score -1):

it would normally be impossible unless:

1. the wielder ran out of mana.
2. the wielder has a huge amount of mana.
3. the wilder concentrates all of there mana away from the sword.

Comment: Running out of Mana is detrimental to a mage (In the black clover universe) it causes exhaustion which would make it impossible to lift those 2 heavy swords, and in extreme cases loss of consciousness.